# How to install mysqli on SunOS

Tags: php, unix, mysqli, sunos

I'm doing a school project using Drupal; and the school give us a SunOS server to use. the detailed information after "uname -a" is:

```
SunOS SERVER-NAME 5.10 Generic_141414-07 sun4v sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-T200
```

I followed the command from lecturer installed mysql, apache and PHP. The php version is 5.3.0, apache version is 2.2, mysql version 5.1.36.

Drupal requires mysqli plugin for PHP, but by looking through the phpinfo() I found that there's no information about the mysqli extension.

I searched online, and from [mysqli installation guide](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php) it says that for Unix OS, the mysqli needs to be installed when compiling PHP. I searched about compile PHP, seems it's quite tedious to do it on SunOS, and several people had some bugs when doing so.

Also it's mentioned online that in order to install mysqli, Ubuntu user may do:

```
apt-get install php5-mysql
```

But seems I cannot get the php5-mysql package.

I think if I can get the mysqli.so extension for SunOS, and enable that extension in my php.ini, this problem can be solved. But there's no where I can get such a extension file.

If no other possible solution, I'm about to compile PHP on SunOS. But I want to check here first: is there any other possible solution?

Thanks a lot.

[Update:]
The phpinfo page is given [here](http://cg3002-21-z.comp.nus.edu.sg/phpinfo.php).

Comment: May you provide the phpinfo()?

Comment: @ArielRamone Hi thanks for reply. I've added in the url for phpinfo page. Meanwhile I'm trying to compile the mysqli extension

Comment: Depending on your server, this may be of use: http://www.opencsw.org/packages/php5_mysqli/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Here's the procedure:

1. download the php source corresponding to your current php version [here](http://php.net/releases/index.php)
2. go to the extension dir and compile the corresponding extension.

That worked but some it failed when I was compiling mysqlnd and pdo_mysql. (did throughly google search until now. but failed to solve)

I think I'll just change to an online host then.